# How to use PHP values in an HTML attribute

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to use an array to determine the colors in a table... However, I believe my syntax is incorrect...

Array :

```
$colors = [
  1 => "red",
  2 => "yellow",
  3 => "green",
];
```

HTML/PHP :

```
<td bgcolor=\"$colors[$row['form1']]\">".$row["form1"]."</td>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is $row['form1']?

Comment: @Nouphal.M it is an imported value from my MYSQL database, the database holds values ranging from 1-3

Comment: which color you need to show from array ? does form1 gives any colour name'

Comment: But what is it? integer or string?

Comment: @VigneswaranS It depends on the value from the MYSQL table... the colors red, yellow, and green.

Comment: @Nouphal.M It is an int

Comment: is $row["form1"]==index of colour ?

Comment: @VigneswaranS Yes it is

Comment: You need to echo in order to get text from array. But you did not specify what is error message?

Comment: @Michael Thanks! Works like a charm. However, there are a few ages that are off by a few months, i.e. 04/12/08 returned age = 8 it there any way I can fix this?

Comment: You're right, because of roundings... Take this instead: `update table set age = timestampdiff(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE('04/12/08', '%m/%d/%Y'),  now() )`

Comment: @Michael Thank you! This worked perfectly !!!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
$doc= new DOMDocument(); $doc->loadHTML($html); $colors = array(1 => "red",2 => "yellow",3 => "green");foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td) {if ($td->getAttribute('bgcolor'),$colors) { /* if true then any color in the array is equal to the td's bgcolor*/ } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php echo '<td bgcolor="'.$colors[intval($row['form1'])].'">'.$row["form1"].'</td>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try in this way :

```
<td bgcolor="<?php echo $colors[$row['form1']]; ?>"><?php echo $row['form1']; ?></td>
```

Comment: No luck:( Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This code will work for**

```
<?php
$colors = array(1 => "red", 2 => "yellow", 3 => "green");

$form1=1;
?>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <td>name</td> 
    <td>Class</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor='<?php echo $colors[$form1]; ?>'>test</td> 

        <td>bcs</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>temp</td> <td>mcs</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

change `$form1` varibale value dynamicaly as you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this bro.

```
 <?php

$colors =  array(
    1 => "red",
    2 => "yellow",
     3 => "green",
);

    ?>
    <html>
    <body bgcolor="<?php $row["form1"]=1;// replace it . i have assigned it as 1
    $r=$row["form1"];
    echo $colors[$r];?>"><?php echo $r; ?> 
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check array is created in right way means there is any error in it....and $row['form1'] value is in correct format

to print array
print_r($colors);exit;

after that this will work

$colors = array(1=>"red",2 => "yellow",3 => "green");

```
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="<?php echo $colors[2];?>"><?php echo $colors[2]; ?></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create an array

```
$colors =  array("a" => "red", "b" => "yellow","c" => "green");
```

HTML code with PHP

```
<td bgcolor="<?php echo $colors['a'];?>"> <?php echo $row['form1'] ?> </td>
```

Hope this will help you.